# how to run Update statement from field in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

i have a query that returns 1 column
this column is a string containing an update statement
how can i run all updates by runing this query?

```
SELECT  'UPDATE TOP (' + CAST([Deploy] AS varchar(10)) + ') TRV
        SET     TRV.SourceStationID = ' + CAST([Station_From] AS varchar(10)) + ',
                TRV.MissingStationSourceCode = 888
        FROM    [Tickets].[dbo].TCK_STG_Fact_Contract_Magnetic_Travels1 TRV
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Tickets].[dbo].[TCK_DWH_Dim_Date]                  DAT ON  CAST(TRV.[ExitDate] AS DATE) = CAST(DAT.Date AS DATE)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Tickets].[dbo].[TCK_DWH_Dim_Manual_PartOfDay]      POD ON  DATEPART(HOUR,TRV.[ExitDate]) = POD.PartOfDay_Hour
        WHERE   DAT.Day_Type_Code = ' + CAST([Day_Type_Code] AS varchar(10)) + '
            AND POD.PartOfDay_Code = ' + CAST([PartOfDay_Code] AS varchar(10)) + '
            AND TRV.DestinationStation = ' + CAST([DestinationStation] AS varchar(10)) + '
            AND TRV.SourceStationID IS NULL'
FROM    [Tickets].[dbo].[TCK_TMP_Fact_ALL_Travels_History_FromMissing]
```

Comment: This is dynamic SQL.  You need to use `exec` (or better yet `exec spexecutesql` to run the code.

Comment: This looks like a severe [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why don't you start at the beginning and tell us what you're *really* trying to achieve here.

Comment: Also, an `UPDATE` with a `TOP` is odd enough, but an `UPDATE` with a `TOP` and without an `ORDER BY` is a recipe for *very* inconsistent results (not that you can have an `ORDER BY` in an `UPDATE`, and why it's odd to have a `TOP`).

Comment: i want to run multiple updates. no need for order by because im just assigning rows to value, each update remove those rows from next update.

Comment: I stand by that this appears to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and that we need to understand what your real goal is here.

Comment: both exec and exec spexecutesql dont work inside the query. need them to run for each row

Comment: @Gines: You need to iterate through the results using a cursor and use `EXEC` (or `sp_executesql`) for each row. But I'm with Larnu here. You would get better help if you explained what underlying problem you try to solve here.

Comment: I guess its related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196072/tsql-dynamic-update-of-topn-rows

Comment: i will try to explain what im doing using example. i have first travels table, each row has a value for origin station but is missing the destination station and each row represent a single travel. second table i have statistics which show for each source all the destinations and next to each destination i have the amount of rows(calculated already from the totals of the first table - travels). i need to assign the destination in the first table. i used a cursor inside a procedure with a loop - that takes more then 30 minutes. i created this query/table holding the UPDATE command in each row

Comment: i used that inside a cursor again - the result is the same, too long

Comment: @Gines  I think you should just create a question detailing the problem you are having per your comment just above mine.  Provide some source data and the table structure, as well as what your desired output is and you will likely get pointed in the right direction on how to best solve this.  You have asked two questions already about your initial solution not working very well, but this is because your initial solution is simply not a very good solution.  Ask a question about your situation (rather than your attempt at solving it) and you will get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments I want to make before you read this answer:

1. I still believe this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and that we should really be answering the *real* problem you have; what ever that is (you haven't told us).
2. I have answered the question literally. This will be far from performant and it's still not got an order for the `TOP`.
3. This is **untested** due to a lack of sample data.

Anyway, you can do this with a `CURSOR` and a **parametrised** dynamic statement. I have **guessed** your data types, and as I have no sample data I cannot test to see if this is valid. If the dynamic statement errors, you'll have to trouble shoot that on your own, as I can't run it (obviously after fixing the data types in **all** locations).

I've also removed the 3 part naming and enforced a connection to the `Tickets` database prior to the batch.

```sql
USE Tickets;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'UPDATE TOP (@Deploy) TRV' + @CRLF + --Don't forget, this translates to @Deploy Arbirtrary rows, not the "top" @Deploy rows, due to a lack of any ordering.
           N'SET TRV.SourceStationID = @StationFrom,' + @CRLF +
           N'    TRV.MissingStationSourceCode = 888' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM [dbo].TCK_STG_Fact_Contract_Magnetic_Travels1 TRV' + @CRLF +
           N'     LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TCK_DWH_Dim_Date] DAT ON CAST(TRV.[ExitDate] AS DATE) = CAST(DAT.Date AS DATE)' + @CRLF +
           N'     LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TCK_DWH_Dim_Manual_PartOfDay] POD ON DATEPART(HOUR,TRV.[ExitDate]) = POD.PartOfDay_Hour' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE DAT.Day_Type_Code = @DayTypeCode' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND POD.PartOfDay_Code = @PartOfDayCode' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND TRV.DestinationStation = @DestinationStation' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND TRV.SourceStationID IS NULL;';

DECLARE Missing_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT Deploy,
       Station_From,
       Day_Type_Code,
       PartOfDay_Code,
       DestinationStation
FROM [dbo].[TCK_TMP_Fact_ALL_Travels_History_FromMissing]

DECLARE @Deploy int, --Assumed data type, due to being used in TOP
        @StationFrom int, --Guessed Datatype
        @DayTypeCode int, --Guessed Datatype
        @PartOfDayCode int, --Guessed Data Type
        @DestinationStation varchar(10); --Guessed Data Type

OPEN Missing_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM Missing_Cursor
INTO @Deploy, @StationFrom, @DayTypeCode, @PartOfDayCode, @DestinationStation;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    --Uses same assumed data types
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Deploy int, @StationFrom int, @DayTypeCode int, @PartOfDayCode int, @DestinationStation varchar(10)', @Deploy, @StationFrom, @DayTypeCode, @PartOfDayCode, @DestinationStation;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Missing_Cursor
    INTO @Deploy, @StationFrom, @DayTypeCode, @PartOfDayCode, @DestinationStation;

END

CLOSE Missing_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Missing_Cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

suggestions here did it with the same time.
what solved the performance issues was adding 2 indexes
thx all for trying to help